# Haskell "as patterns" in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell, pattern-matching

`compress` is a function that removes consecutive duplicates of list elements.

```
compress (x:ys@(y:_))
    | x == y    = compress ys
    | otherwise = x : compress ys
compress ys = ys
```

Now, isn't `x:ys` is the same pattern as `y:_` in `(x:ys@(y:_))`? If it is, then how this function correctly executes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not the same. The @ symbol is used to give a name to a parameter and to match against a pattern after the @ symbol.

In your example `ys` is a synonym for `(y:_)`. Writing it as `(x:(ys@(y:_)))` makes it more clear. `x` is the first element of the list, `y` is the second element of the list, `ys` is the list without the first element `x`.